# how to add profiler to the react dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, profiler

I want the profiler(option) section in the in developer tools in the React section.

I am unable to get it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nySib7ipZdk

I have installed the react dev tools extension also.

https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

I have gone through the above page and also the youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nySib7ipZdk

It doesn't help me.

Comment: Profiler works when the dev tool detects a React app > 16.5, what's your version ?

Comment: Additionally it does not work in production build

Comment: my react version is of "^16.8.6" and also I am checking in development mode only. @MosèRaguzzini

Comment: chrome extension is up to date ?

Comment: **Yes, @MosèRaguzzini I have the latest version of 3.6.0**

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini

 could you Check this image URL so that you can see how I am getting

[link](https://pasteboard.co/Ikam7PL.png)